# Apache serving incomplete responses from smb mounted directories

Tags: apache-2.2, http, server-message-block

I'm running "Apache/2.2.9 (Debian) PHP/5.2.6-1+lenny3 with Suhosin-Patch" inside a virtual machine (debian lenny, up2date) with NAT and about 60% of any http response gets served "incomplete" when serving requests from smb mounted directories (i.e. from the vm host).

My problem is, i cannot see any pattern which response when fails, because they kind of rotate. But what i can see is, that some requests like jquery ui always gets truncated at the same position (javascript console reports syntax error).

This is an example header of a response that was incomplete:

```
Date    Fri, 04 Sep 2009 21:09:38 GMT
Server  Apache/2.2.9 (Debian) PHP/5.2.6-1+lenny3 with Suhosin-Patch
Last-Modified   Sat, 20 Jun 2009 11:53:52 GMT
Etag    "1810-2f074-46cc64b731400"
Accept-Ranges   bytes
Content-Length  192628
Connection  close
Content-Type    application/javascript
```

Enabled apache2 mods:

```
alias.conf            authz_user.load  dir.load          php5.load
alias.load            autoindex.conf   env.load          rewrite.load
auth_basic.load       autoindex.load   mime.conf         setenvif.conf
authn_file.load       cgi.load         mime.load         setenvif.load
authz_default.load    deflate.conf     negotiation.conf  status.conf
authz_groupfile.load  deflate.load     negotiation.load  status.load
authz_host.load       dir.conf         php5.conf
```

Only .js and .png files are affected in my particular project. The "main request" always loads fine.

**update:**
`apache2ctl -m` output:

```
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 log_config_module (static)
 logio_module (static)
 mpm_prefork_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 alias_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authz_default_module (shared)
 authz_groupfile_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 cgi_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 php5_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
Syntax OK
```

Comment: To list the loaded Apache 2 modules please run httpd -M, that what you have provided is just a list of files and does not help us in maybe locating the issue.

Comment: Please list the full response headers. The example you gave doesn't include the response status code.

Is the reported Content-Length (192628) the same as the actual size of the file you are trying to download?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've seen this when serving files from SMB- or CIFS-mounted shares. Try turning off [sendfile](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#enablesendfile) support using:

```
EnableSendfile Off
```

You can do this in the main server configuration, `.htacces` file or in a vhost/directory block.

Comment: Glad to be of service!

Comment: PS to make it easier for Google and others with the same problem can you edit your question to say you're serving from an SMB mount? Thanks!

Comment: @markdrayton: done

Comment: OMG This has stumped me for the past week. We ran into it when we switched a Docker-based web application (FileRun) from accessing volumes over NFS to accessing them over SMBv3. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Well, i switched the files from a mounted windows smb-share to a local directory, and it now works fine.
I don't have the time to investigate this further, but i think the problem was not related to apache itself.